# How this website see Real location?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, deanonymization, website

The website xvideos.com see your real location ( in left top side the icon of your real locations it's showed ) even with Safest Security Level
Why ?

Comment: Real location or the location of the exit node ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more related to how the remote site is working rather than Tor

Answer (score 1):

I tested right now  ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) and the website just appear the exit node location, are you sure your connection did not coincidentally fall into an exit-node of your own country?